# Can't publish J2EE project to tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, groovy

I have a Java project using Groovy and Java mixed. Now I want to publish it to my tomcat, but it says

```
Could not publish to the server. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Platform : OS X / Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 / Java 1.6 / Tomcat 7.0.39

How can I deal with this issue ? I can deploy a new create Dynamic Web Project, but not my exist project.

My server configuration :

[image]

Comment: Do you have a more complete stack trace from the Error Log view? Is your existing project different in some way from a new dynamic web project?

Answer (score 0):

My Jar files are way too old, I just deploy my project into Tomcat manually and found a lot of error log.

Just update them into newer version.